# Get links within a PDF file in php

Tags: php, pdf

Is there someway to get links within pdf file using php?
When I upload a pdf file, I want to get the links to insert in database.

I have used pdftotext but this tool returns only pure text. I need to get the links within pdf file.

I searched the internet and found nothing.

Comment: Try `pdftotext`?

Comment: Yes, but it doesn't get the links. It shows pure text.

Answer (score 0):

You can access link annotations through the [SetaPDF-Core](https://www.setasign.com/products/setapdf-core/demos/replace-link-targets/#p-342) component (not free, and I'm related to the company behind). You can also modify the link targets as shown in the linked demo.

If you also need to access links (or better URLs) within text, you can use the already mentioned command-line tool `pdftotext` or the [SetaPDF-Extractor](https://www.setasign.com/products/setapdf-extractor/details/) component (also not free). The SetaPDF-Extractor also comes with a demo that creates annotations based on the found URLs.